# How to make the menu my sticky header in wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, header, sticky

So far I have the following header on my site:

[image]

Right now, when you scroll down the page, the sticky header is the LOGO, Phone numnber and the Request service button in red. How could I change this to use the Services menu below to be my sticky header instead?

I checked the code of the Header.php and found the following lines:

```
// Sticky header

if(isset($theme_options['enable_sticky_header']) &&     $theme_options['enable_sticky_header']) {
$header_add_class = ' class="'.esc_attr('sticky-header main-header').'"';
} else {
  $header_add_class = ' class="'.esc_attr('main-header').'"';
}
?>
<header<?php echo $header_add_class; ?>>
<div class="container<?php echo esc_attr($header_container_add_class); ?>">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
 
    <div class="header-left logo">
    <?php
    // Center logo
    if(isset($theme_options['header_logo_position']) &&    $theme_options['header_logo_position'] == 'center'): ?>
        <?php magnium_header_center_show(); ?>
      <?php else: ?>
          <?php magnium_header_left_show(); ?>
        <?php endif;
        // Center logo END
        ?>
      </div>
  
      <div class="header-center">
      <?php 
      // Center logo
      if(isset($theme_options['header_logo_position']) &&     $theme_options['header_logo_position'] == 'center'):
      ?>
        <?php magnium_header_left_show(); ?>
      <?php else: ?>
        <?php magnium_header_center_show(); ?>
      <?php 
      endif; 
      // Center logo END
      ?>
      </div>

      <div class="header-right">
        <?php magnium_header_right_show(); ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<?php magnium_menu_below_header_show(); ?>
 </header>
```

I guess this line `magnium_menu_below_header_show()` is responsible for displaying the menu, but I really do not know where to search it. Although I looked in functions.php, I could not find it.

I know I could use a plugin, but I just do not want to always rely on plugins if I can make it by myself.

Comment: Which theme are you using and can you send me the link of your site thank you.

Comment: thanks Umesh, but i managed to fix this issue already. I ended up using a plugin that literally did the job in 2 minutes. Thanks though